# Is there a functionality like Sublime's "HTML: Encode Special Characters" in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, html-encode

I'm looking something like the functionality given in Sublime Text by the shortcut (windows) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> named "HTML:  Encode Special Characters" but in **IntelliJ IDEA**. This functionality is able to transform this (as a example):

```
I'm a special character phrase "áéíóú ñ"
```

Into this:

```
I'm a special character phrase &quot;&aacute;&eacute;&iacute;&oacute;&uacute; &ntilde;&quot;
```

Only by surrounding the specified text and pressing the shortcut key combination given above (again, in windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>).

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE (07-04-2016)**

By now, Intellij Idea support this feature natively (version 2016). You need to select the text you want to transform and (in OSX) Cmd+Shift+A and type "Encode" then select the action "Encode XML/HTML Special Characters"

[image: encode Intellij Idea]

The only caveats are that this only works (to my knowledge) in html strings.

Comment: "Encode XML/HTML Special Characters" can be accessed using [Ctrl + Shift + A] for windows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not supported by IntelliJ directly, but a plugin called String Manipulation can help

From the [plugin page](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162):

> Provide actions for text manipulation:
>
> - Un/Escape selected Java text
> - Un/Escape selected JavaScript text
> - **Un/Escape selected HTML text**
> - Un/Escape selected XML text
> - Un/Escape selected SQL text
> - Un/Escape selected PHP text
> - Trim selected text
> - Trim all spaces in selected text
> - Remove all spaces in selected text
> - De/Encode selected text as URL
> - Convert selected text to Camel Case
> - Convert selected text to Constant Case
> - Capitalize selected text
> - Encode selected text to MD5 Hex16
> - De/Encode selected text to Base64
> - Remove empty lines
> - Convert non ASCII to escaped Unicode
> - Convert escaped Unicode to String
> - Grep selected text, All lines not matching input text wil be removed. (Does not work in column mode)
> - Increment/Decrement selected text. Duplicate line and increment/decrement all numbers found.

Comment: Thanks! with this plugin the full keyboard shorcut is Alt + Shift + m and then press '5' (tested in windows).