# Convert/Encode html special characters on copy or by selection in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: html, intellij-idea, encoding

Lets say that i want to copy the following to an HTML file (inside IntelliJ Idea IDE). (as text)

```
The <head> element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the <html> tag and the <body> tag.
```

And have it converted to this

```
The &lt;head&gt; element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the &lt;html&gt; tag and the &lt;body&gt; tag.
```

so that it will be copied as printable text not as HTML tags

I usually use this [web2generators.com | HTML Entities Encoder / Decoder](http://www.web2generators.com/html-based-tools/online-html-entities-encoder-and-decoder) but, I want a faster method.

I have also found this question [Is there a functionality like Sublime's “HTML: Encode Special Characters” in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367890/is-there-a-functionality-like-sublimes-html-encode-special-characters-in-int), but the update to the question (Which is a partial solution) still doesn't solve the tag problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [String Manipulation Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162?pr=idea). It won't convert text as it is pasted so you would need to paste the text, select the relevant text and then choose String manipulation->escape/unescape->escape html (or define a macro to avoid too much clicking)